# adding subtracting PSD vibration data

Tags: power-spectral-density, random-process

We performed some vibration tests on a shaker, with two accelerometers on our setup.
One was on the shaker table, to measure the input signal. And the other one was on a flexible part of our test setup, this is considered the output signal. The input was zero mean band limited white noise acceleration, between 100 and 1200 Hz.

The data that we have from the accelerometers are the acceleration spectral densities, in g^2/Hz, of the input and output. These are the *absolute* accelerations of the input and output. But now I need the *relative* acceleration, between output and input. And also the relative velocity and the relative displacement between input and output.

Can I just add or subtract PSD values to find the relative signals?
[image: applied acceleration on mass-spring-damper system]

Comment: you mean you can *divide* them, not *subtract* those **linear** quantities, right? (I'm assuming your system *is* linear, i.e. if you scale the input by a factor of 2, the output will be scaled with exactly 2 as well, right?)

Comment: Unfortunately the system is not linear. That is what I am studying now.
So we repeated the test at different input levels, 2 g_rms, 4 g_rms, 6 g_rms etc. Then we noticed that the output levels were nonlinear, they did not scale with the input levels.

Comment: We can write the (mechanical) stiffness and (mechanical) damping as a function of the input accelerations that I mentioned above, but it is required to plot stiffness against the displacement occurring in the system and to plot damping against velocity occurring in the system. 
For example, a spring force normally is plotted against the displacement *difference* between both ends of the spring. That requires a subtraction of the displacement of both ends if both ends are moving.

Comment: Ah well, but if its not linear, then the absolute difference isn't much help either. You will first need to select some nonlinear *model* of your device and try to fill in the parameters of that!

Comment: The output data looks somewhat like the response of a single mass-spring-damper (MSD) system. So I could fit the output data to the response of a MSD system. Then use that to determine the rms velocity and rms displacement. This should be done for each test level separately, given the nonlinearity.
But I figured it would be more neat to get data like the rms velocity and rms displacement straight out of the measured data instead of fitting the acceleration results to a function and then use that function for estimating the rms velocity and rms displacement.

Comment: well, I think you basically got the point: you're trying to model a system that involves nonlinearity. So, to describe that, your model needs to have some component that's nonlinear. I'm not very versed in modelling of mechanical systems, so MSD systems just don't tell me anything on a formulaic level. But: if that model happens to be a system of ordinary differential equations, maybe adding some unknown exponent $\alpha$ to the observed displacement and the appropriate multiples of $\alpha$ to all derivatives thereof might be enough to give you a parameterized nonlinearity that you can fit

Comment: … to your observation. You're right – you want to fit your model to your reality, not the other way around. But the PSD of a nonlinear system is very hard to work with – it's more or less meaningless as system description, as nonlinearity has the abiltiy to introduce new frequency components to your output instead of just "weighing" input frequency components. So, you couldn't tell whether an output density around some frequency is the result of a linear operation on the input at the same frequency, or the intermodulation of two (or more!) other input components, or any combination thereof.

Comment: A standard MSD system would be:
$m \ddot{x} + c \dot{x} + k x = F(t)$
(mass x acceleration + damping x velocity + stiffness x displacement = force)
A first guess for a nonlinear one would be:
$m \ddot{x} + c \dot{x} +c_{nonlin} \dot{x}^a+ k x +k_{nonlin} x^b = F(t)$
But to find the nonlinear terms I would need more info about $\dot{x}$ and $x$. Thus my original question, how can I get that if only the PSD values for $\ddot{x}$ are available.

Comment: I've worked on very similar set-ups in the past. You are looking for an empirical transfer-function estimate, and it is defined under stationary conditions (by applying the noise excitation for a long time and removing transients). But you need to take a bit of care, so you are getting the right input and output. How is the motion coupled from table to flexible structure? I'm guessing it is a boundary constraint on the displacement? Can you draw a free-body diagram with equivalent point masses?

Comment: Do you have MATLAB available? If you do, then manipulating the frequency domain data for you purpose is very simple. You integrate in the frequency domain by multiplying the Fourier transform with $1/j \omega$, but MATLAB has built-in functions to do all that for you very robustly numerically

Comment: Hi, yes the tests are done under stationary conditions, the test time was much longer than any of the transient responses. 

I added a drawing of the test setup to the original post. The test setup is connected with a very stiff adapter plate to the electrodynamic shaker. The electrodynamic shaker in itself is a very stiff system. The applied load is in the form of an *enforced acceleration*, $\ddot{u}$, with an acceleration PSD.

Comment: So I only have the PSD of $\ddot{x}$ and $\ddot{u}$. Now I would like to have the PSD of $\ddot{z}=\ddot{x}-\ddot{u}$.

I do have access to a MATLABworkstation but I do most of my work in Octave due to license shortage. Working in the frequency domain is no problem. The way I understood is, is that with a PSD the phase data is lost, unlike with a Fourier transform of the data. Now I wonder if it is still possible to find the PSD of $\ddot{z}=\ddot{x}-\ddot{u}$. Do I need the phase data or any kind of correlation data for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand the question:

1. You have the power spectral density estimates $S_\ddot{x}$ and $S_\ddot{u}$.
2. You want to obtain the power spectral density estimate $S_z$ where $z = x - u$.
3. You would like to find $S_x$ and $S_u$ in the frequency domain.

The power spectral density of $z$ with $z = x - u$ would be the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation $R_z(\tau)$, which is something like (in the stationary case)
$$
R_z(\tau) = E\left[ \left( x(t) - z(t) \right) \left( x(t + \tau) - z(t + \tau) \right) \right] = R_x(\tau) - R_{xu}(\tau) - R_{ux}(\tau) + R_u(\tau)
$$
implying
$$
S_z(j \omega) = S_x(j \omega) - 2 \mathrm{Re}\left( S_{xu}(j \omega) \right) + S_u(j \omega)
$$
If $x$ and $u$ are *uncorrelated*, then
$$
S_z(j \omega) = S_x(j \omega) + S_u(j \omega)
$$
but that is not the case for you; you need the cross spectral density function as well.

Time-integration in the frequency domain is equivalent to multiplying with $1/j\omega$. As it appears you are only working with power spectral density estimates, I am a bit at loss for finding good numerical methods, but I've included a MATLAB example of a crude method below:

```
clear

Fs = 1e5; % sampling freq.
Ts = 1/Fs;
Nsamp = 1e5; % number of samples
t = (0:Nsamp-1)*Ts; % time vector

x = randn(1,Nsamp); % excitation signal

[B,A] = butter(3,2*pi*1e4,'s'); % example dynamical system
W = tf(B,A); % plant/dynamics/filter
Wd = W*tf('s')^2; % 2nd derivative of filter output (should be at least proper for numerical reasons)

u = lsim(W,x,t,'foh'); % find the filter response (first order hold for better interpolation)
u = u(501:end); % remove most of the transient
ud = lsim(Wd,x,t,'foh'); % find the filter response
ud = ud(501:end); % remove most of the transient

WIN = kaiser(numel(u)/10,38); % windowing to reduce artifacts
[Pu,Fu] = pwelch(u,WIN,[],numel(u),Fs,'power','onesided'); % PSD of filter
[Pud,Fud] = pwelch(ud,WIN,[],numel(ud),Fs,'power','onesided'); % PSD of deriv. filter

figure(1), clf
semilogy(Fu,Pu)
hold on
semilogy(Fud,Pud)

II = (1/(2*pi))./(1i.*Fud(2:end)); % 1/(j 2 pi f)
Pudi = (II.*conj(II)).^2.*Pud(2:end); % basic time integration in freq. domain
semilogy(Fud(2:end),Pudi)
```

In my experience, given that you know the excitation force $f$ and output $x$, it is usually the transfer-function $x(j\omega)/f(j\omega) = G(j \omega)$ that is interesting. This transfer-function can be estimated using e.g.
$$
G(j\omega) = \frac{S_{xx}(j\omega)}{S_{xf}(j\omega)}
$$
A numerical example is given below in MATLAB:

```
clear

Fs = 1e4; % sampling freq.
Ts = 1/Fs;
Nsamp = 1e6; % number of samples
t = (0:Nsamp-1)*Ts; % time vector

f = randn(1,Nsamp); % excitation signal

G = rss(3); % random plant/dynamics/filter

x = lsim(G,f,t,'zoh'); % find the plant response
x = x(1001:end); % remove most of the transient
f = f(1001:end);

WIN = hamming(numel(x)/4);
[Pxx,Fxx] = pwelch(x,WIN,[],numel(x),Fs,'onesided'); % Power Spectral Density
[Pxf,Fxf] = cpsd(f,x,WIN,[],numel(x),Fs,'onesided'); % Cross Power Spectral Density

Gest = Pxx./Pxf; % estimated response
[MAG,PHASE] = bode(G,2*pi*Fxx); % "true" response

%%
figure(1), clf

subplot(2,1,1)
loglog(Fxx,abs(Gest))
hold on
loglog(Fxx,MAG(:))

subplot(2,1,2)
semilogx(Fxx,(180/pi)*unwrap(angle(Gest)))
hold on
semilogx(Fxx(:),PHASE(:))
```